# How to sum columns from two tables if the month match and group by month

Tags: mysql

Currently I achieved to do it with a single table with this query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) as month, SUM(total) as total FROM invoices         GROUP BY month ORDER BY month ASC
```

But now I'm going crazy trying to return the same result from two columns, let's say total1 and total2, and group by month, if there is no invoice in a month in one of the columns the result should be cero.

Tables structure and expected result:

```
invoices payments
date     date
total    income


month      totalInvoices   totalPayments    
1         10005            8017  
2         756335           5019  
3         541005           8017  
4         34243            8870
```

How do I achieve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Table structure and expected output please.

Comment: I fixed that, @YusufHassan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a third element to the query structure which provides a complete list of all relevant years/months. This might be an existing table or a subquery, but the overall query will follow the structure outlined below:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE invoices
>     (`id` int, `invdate` datetime, `invtotal` numeric);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO invoices
>     (`id`, `invdate`, `invtotal`)
> VALUES
>     (1, '2017-01-21 00:00:00', 12.45);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE payments
>     (`id` int, `paydate` datetime, `paytotal` numeric);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO payments
>     (`id`, `paydate`, `paytotal`)
> VALUES
>     (1, '2017-02-21 00:00:00', 12.45);
> ```

> ```
> select
>     ym.year, ym.month, inv.invtotal, pay.paytotal
> from (
>       SELECT
>           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM invdate) as year
>         , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invdate) as month
>       FROM invoices  
>       UNION
>       SELECT
>           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM paydate) as year
>         , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM paydate) as month
>       FROM payments  
>       ) ym
> left join (
>     SELECT
>         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM invdate) as year
>       , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invdate) as month
>       , SUM(invtotal) as invtotal 
>     FROM invoices         
>     GROUP BY year, month 
>     ) inv on ym.year = inv.year and ym.month = inv.month
> left join (
>     SELECT
>         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM paydate) as year
>       , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM paydate) as month
>       , SUM(paytotal) as paytotal 
>     FROM payments         
>     GROUP BY year, month 
>     ) pay on ym.year = pay.year and ym.month = pay.month;
> ```
>
> ```
> year | month | invtotal | paytotal
> -----|-------|----------|--------|
> 2017 |     1 |       12 |   null |
> 2017 |     2 |     null |     12 |
> ```

In my example the "third element" is the subquery **ym** but this may be too inefficient for your actual query, but it should server to identify how to co-ordinate data over disparate time ranges.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=927250d4e395616b39637d7dec7e6013)*